# How to extract convolutional neural network from Keras model object to Networkx DiGraph object keeping weights as an edge attribute?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, networkx

I'm interested in using the [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/) [Python](https://www.python.org/) package to perform [network analysis](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/21642850.2018.1521283) on [convolutional neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network). To achieve this I want to extract the [edge](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphEdge.html) and [weight](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191447/what-is-the-definition-of-an-weighted-graph) information from [Keras model objects](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) and put them into a [Networkx Digraph object](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html) where it can be (1) [written to a graphml file](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml.html) and (2) be subject to the graph analysis tools available in Networkx.

Before jumping in further, let me clarify and how to consider [pooling](https://machinelearningmastery.com/pooling-layers-for-convolutional-neural-networks/). Pooling (examples: [max](https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Max-pooling_/_Pooling), or [average](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/pooling.py#L117)) means that the entries within a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) [window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) will be [aggregated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function), creating an ambiguity on 'which' entry would be used in the graph I want to create. To resolve this, I would like every possible choice included in the graph as I can account for this later as needed.

For the sake of example, let's consider doing this with [VGG16](https://neurohive.io/en/popular-networks/vgg16/). [Keras](https://keras.io/) makes it pretty easy to [access the weight](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/)s while looping over the [layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers).

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

model = VGG16()

for layer_index, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    GW = layer.get_weights()
    if layer_index == 0:
        print(layer_index, layer.get_config()['name'], layer.get_config()['batch_input_shape'])
    elif GW:
        W, B =  GW
        print(layer_index, layer.get_config()['name'], W.shape, B.shape)
    else:
        print(layer_index, layer.get_config()['name'])
```

Which will print the following:

```
0 input_1 (None, 224, 224, 3)
1 block1_conv1 (3, 3, 3, 64) (64,)
2 block1_conv2 (3, 3, 64, 64) (64,)
3 block1_pool
4 block2_conv1 (3, 3, 64, 128) (128,)
5 block2_conv2 (3, 3, 128, 128) (128,)
6 block2_pool
7 block3_conv1 (3, 3, 128, 256) (256,)
8 block3_conv2 (3, 3, 256, 256) (256,)
9 block3_conv3 (3, 3, 256, 256) (256,)
10 block3_pool
11 block4_conv1 (3, 3, 256, 512) (512,)
12 block4_conv2 (3, 3, 512, 512) (512,)
13 block4_conv3 (3, 3, 512, 512) (512,)
14 block4_pool
15 block5_conv1 (3, 3, 512, 512) (512,)
16 block5_conv2 (3, 3, 512, 512) (512,)
17 block5_conv3 (3, 3, 512, 512) (512,)
18 block5_pool
19 flatten
20 fc1 (25088, 4096) (4096,)
21 fc2 (4096, 4096) (4096,)
22 predictions (4096, 1000) (1000,)
```

For the convolutional layers, I've read that the tuples will represent (filter_x, filter_y, filter_z, num_filters) where filter_x, filter_y, filter_z give the shape of the filter and num_filters is the number of filters. There's one bias term for each filter, so the last tuple in these rows will also equal the number of filters.

While I've [read explanations](https://machinelearningmastery.com/convolutional-layers-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/) of how the convolutions within a convolutional neural network behave conceptually, I seem to be having a mental block when I get to handling the shapes of the layers in the model object.

Once I know how to loop over the edges of the Keras model, with Networkx I should be able to easily code the construction of the Networkx object. The code for this might loosely resemble something like this, where `keras_edges` is an iterable that contains tuples formatted as (in_node, out_node, edge_weight).

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph()

g.add_weighted_edges_from(keras_edges)

nx.write_graphml(g, 'vgg16.graphml')
```

So to be specific, how do I loop over all the edges in a way that accounts for the shape of the layers and the pooling in the way I described above?

Comment: Keras doesn't have the concept of edges. Speaking in an "exact" code language, what do you expect to obtain that is considered an edge? In other words, what do you want in `keras_edges`? If I understood well your description for poolings, this will be overwhelming. For convolutional networks, which perform `(image_size_x - kernel_size_x + 1) * (image_size_y - kernel_size_y + 1) * kernel_size_x * kernel_size_y * input_channels * output_channels`  multiplications per image, getting these edges (whatever they are) would be really tough.

Comment: If I may add an extra, the 4 dimensions of a filter are `(size1, size2, input_channels, output_channels)`, there is no `z`, unless you consider `z` as channels. These convolutions are for `2D` images.

Comment: Great point. In this context, just like in  a multilayer  perceptron, the edges represent contributions of previous nodes that are weighted (i.e. parametric transformations).

Comment: I had to fix a mistake above (see edit history if you're curious), but ```keras_edges``` would be an iterable containing tuples formatted as (in_node, out_node, weight).

Comment: You make a really good point about the size of such a network. As you point out, the number of multiplications grows quickly with the image size. Is there a usuable concept of a smallest image that would produce a digraph with all the weights in the model?

Comment: Thank for the added information on the dimensions. I was thinking of ```z``` as the depth of the filer, which is an idea I got from https://machinelearningmastery.com/convolutional-layers-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/

Comment: Yes, the smallest image has the size of the kernel.

Comment: You can see it as a sort of depth indeed, but it always occupies the entire depth and never slides in the depth direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211029/discussion-between-galen-and-daniel-moller).

Answer (score 0):

Since Keras doesn't have an edge element, and a Keras node seems to be something totally different (a Keras node is an entire layer when it's used, it's the layer as presented in the graph of the model)

So, assuming you are using the smallest image possible (which is equal to the kernel size), and that you're creating nodes manually (sorry, I don't know how it works in networkx):

For a convolution that:

- Has `i` input channels (channels in the image that comes in)
- Has `o` output channels (the selected number of filters in keras)
- Has `kernel_size = (x, y)`

You already know the weights, which are shaped `(x, y, i, o)`.

You would have something like:

```
#assuming a node here is one pixel from one channel only:

#kernel sizes x and y
kSizeX = weights.shape[0]
kSizeY = weights.shape[1]

#in and out channels
inChannels = weights.shape[2]
outChannels = weights.shape[3]

#slide steps x
stepsX = image.shape[0] - kSizeX + 1
stepsY = image.shape[1] - kSizeY + 1


#stores the final results
all_filter_results = []

for ko in range(outChannels): #for each output filter

    one_image_results = np.zeros((stepsX, stepsY))

    #for each position of the sliding window 
    #if you used the smallest size image, start here
    for pos_x in range(stepsX):      
        for pos_y in range(stepsY):

            #storing the results of a single step of a filter here:
            one_slide_nodes = []

            #for each weight in the filter
            for kx in range(kSizeX):
                for ky in range(kSizeY):
                    for ki in range(inChannels):

                        #the input node is a pixel in a single channel
                        in_node = image[pos_x + kx, pos_y + ky, ki]

                        #one multiplication, single weight x single pixel
                        one_slide_nodes.append(weights[kx, ky, ki, ko] * in_node)

                        #so, here, you have in_node and weights

            #the results of each step in the slide is the sum of one_slide_nodes:
            slide_result = sum(one_slide_nodes)
            one_image_results[pos_x, pos_y] = slide_result   
    all_filter_results.append(one_image_results)
```

Comment: Should ```outChannels = weights[3]``` be ```outChannels = weights.shape[3]```? I get ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    weights[3]
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3```

Comment: `outChannels = weights.shape[3]` the number of output channels. Fixed the answer, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Another minor one is that ```kSyzeY``` should be ```kSizeY``` in one of the weight loops.

Comment: I had guessed smallest image could be set as ```image = np.ones((3,3,3))``` but I get ```in_node = image[pos_x + kx, pos_y + ky, ki]
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 3``` in the traceback.

Comment: Use an `assert weights.shape[2] == image.shape[2]`, I think your weights have more channels than your image.

Comment: Yeah, got an assertion error. Here are the sizes ```>>> weights.shape[2], image.shape[2]
(64, 3)```

Comment: Well, thats it then. You got weights for a `(x, y, 64)` image.